# Laravel 5, access helper function in custom folder inside resources

Tags: php, laravel-5, helper

I have a custom folder inside the resources folder like this : resources/test_folder/index.php

Now i want to access a helper function inside this index.php.

> Getting undefined function error.

Its working fine in the resources/views.Is there any default mapping between the resources/views and helper functions?

Helpers are autoloaded in the composer file like this:

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/Http/GlobalFunctions.php"
        ]
    }
```

Function inside the helper:

```
function debug($data = array())
{
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($data);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `public/index.php` file executes before the composer autoloader is called. You could either include you helper file manuelly on top of the `index.php` (not recommended) or rewrite your logic to use it after loading the autoloader.

Notice that editing your `index.php` file is not recommended. You should use your app directory for your logic.